# In GNUPG Kleopatra, what does "+RSA" do when generating a key?

Tags: gnupg

A customer of ours wants us to create PGP keys similar to those created by GPG's Kleopatra utility when the GUI option "+RSA" is checked. We don't use Kleopatra, and would like to know just what the "+RSA" option does so that we can use the equivalent functionality in the PGP software that we do use.
I have downloaded and installed Kleopatra, read the documentation, and run it with verbose debug logging, but unfortunately, I am none the wiser for having done so.

Does anyone know what +RSA does?

Answer (score 3):

Kleo-genkey RSA with +RSA checked is the same as modern `gpg --full-gen-key` option 1 'RSA and RSA (default)' and is the now-usual (though not mandatory) structure of **a masterkey with usage Sign,Certify and one subkey with usage Encrypt**. RSA with +RSA unchecked creates a single key with usage S,C,E -- a structure common in the past, with GnuPG 1 IIRC, but not recently.